# JQuery - Ajax - Struts2 list

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

Im looking for a little help on getting my JQuery/Ajax call to return a List from a Struts action and populate a DIV with the list elements using s:iterator.

I have the following JQuery

```
   function lookupCustomerJs() {
        alert("lets start");
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "lookupCustomerAjax",  
            data: $('#lookupCustomer').serialize(), 
            success:function(response) {  
                alert("do stuff");
                $('div#custList').replaceWith($(response).find("div#custList"));
            },
            failure:function(response) {
                alert('Ajax call failed');
            },
            error:function(response) {
                alert(exception);
            }
        });  
    }
```

I have a DIV within my page which I then want to iterate the list through

```
                        <div id="custList">
                            <s:iterator status="stat" value="customerList" var="customer">
                                <s:param name="custFName" value="%{customer.firstname}" />
                            </s:iterator>
                        </div>
```

And my Action method which IS called, because when I debug, the debugger goes through the code.

```
private List<Customer> customerList;

public String lookupCustomerAjax() {

    dummyData();

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

This successully calls my Action method, but all I get is the "lets start" alert, then nothing else, no errors, nothing!

So I'm guessing it's just the jQuery/Ajax success:function(response) {  not fireing correctly, but can't see why.

Comment: can you tell . what exactly the error is shown in console. try . firebug/IE developer/Chrome . one of the general cause is in incorrect placement of jquery.js. Also put your function in $(document).ready(function() { });

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the "lookupCustomerAjax" is an invalid url or file name. You should try adding the extension.

Also, for troubleshooting, you should console.log(response) in your succession to see that you are actually get the result.

Comment: But when I run my code in 'debug' and put breakers in the lookupCustomerAjax method, the app goes through the method, it just doesn't seemt to be dropping into any of the success, failure or error part of the jQuery.

Comment: user1160629, you said that "it just doesn't seemt to be dropping into any of the success, failure or error part of the jQuery" which is why I said that you need to give it a valid URL or filename.

I tested this on Firefox, if the filename is not correctly given it will failed without going into success or failure.

Give it a valid filename or path, you should see either a succession or a failure.